# Install .cls and .tex file properly?

Tags: templates

I have a huge question, since I am truly desperate right now.
I am currently writing my bachelor thesis, soon I will have to hand it in and just now my supervisor sent me a customized LaTeX-Thesis-Style that I should use.

I have been trying to get this style to work for my document for a while now, have done lots of googling and searched various topics on this board, but still did not get it to work.

What I received was a "thesis.cls" and a "thesis.tex" file. I have made a "texmf/tex/latex/local" directory in my "Documents" folder, where I have inserted the files and added the path to my MikTeX 2.9 settings. When I now try to use the Style (\documentclass{thesis}), I only get lots of error messages.

These include things like
´

> Too many }'s. \supervisorone{supervisor here}}

or

> Missing \begin{document}. {R

or

> Too many }'s. {Research Group Name}}

I don't really get how the .tex file is supposed to help me and the general procedure of getting this style to work.

It would be really great if someone could give me a brief explanation of how I should proceed to properly use that style.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much do you know about LaTeX? Or is this the first time you're using it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some examples of code would be better.

Comment: Check in the log-file if "your" thesis class has been loaded, If yes, then probably the class is faulty. Ask your supervisor to correct it.

Comment: I have been using LaTeX for a while now, but only with the standard-styles (report or article), and mostly only for typing.

I'm rather positive that it uses my Thesis class, because clicking the error messages opens my Thesis.cls file. 

@egreg What code examples would you like? From the .cls class?

Comment: I suspect that the `thesis.tex` file is just a kind of template to show you how to use the `thesis.cls` file. So you shouldn't put `thesis.tex` in the local `texmf` folder, but use a copy of it to create a new `.tex` document for your thesis.  Since the class is created by your supervisor, it's difficult for us to diagnose this more.

Comment: Put `thesis.tex` in a clean directory (not in your new TEXMF tree) and compile it to make sure that there is nothing wrong with the `.cls` file you've been sent. If that is OK, then make a copy of `thesis.tex` in the working directory where your own document is, open it up and see if you can copy-paste the content of your document into the relevant parts of the new document.

Comment: I sadly don't know if it is free or not, but I managed to fix it now. I have gone through the errors in the .cls file and noticed that there were many brackets not set properly. I have managed to fix them and have now understood that I was supposed to use the .tex file to implement my work.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP fix the problem without showing code.

Comment: If that tempalte you are using really is based on `Thesis.cls` from Sunil Patel, you should immediately stop distributing the template. It is flawed in many ways and should not be used. A new version can be found on latex-templates.com. But better to avoid any templates.